# Listing an application's activity and intent-filters?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I am interested in activating another application's activity. I know from reading the Android SDK that it's probably better to do this with an implicit intent. However, this activity doesn't reside in an application I own, so I don't know the action and category and data flags on the intent-filter.

How can I examine an Android applications metadata like the activity classes and the intent-filters for those activities (if declared in the manifest)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try this.

1. Check on [openintents](http://www.openintents.org/en/)
2. Contact the developer.
3. Use [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) too see the app's manifest.

It might be illegal to use android-apktool. Use it under your own risk.

Comment: I contacted the developer and they sound pretty supportive of me writing a widget for them so they'll provide me with the information. Thanks for the links though!

Answer (score 1):

There is one more solution: you could run this app and look into logcat. All intents are logged, so you could see what is called up. You won't see extra data though.