# List intent filters for installed packages

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to list out the activity intent filters for the packages installed on my phone. This is just for a learning experience, I want to understand what apps can be started with implicit intents and how the intent filters are set up.

Google provides a table for the applications they provide at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html. I’m looking to create a similar list for other applications.

Can I use the PackageManager and dig this info up in code? Does anyone know of an existing app that can do this? Can anyone point me to an existing example to do what I want?

Sorry if this is a duplicate of similar questions like [Listing an application's activity and intent-filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011454/listing-an-applications-activity-and-intent-filters) and [Android -- How to get a list of all available intent filters ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094109/android-how-to-i-get-a-list-of-all-available-intent-filters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to list all intents that a specific application can receive. However, you can get similar (albeit not as expansive) information by creating some intents yourself then using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)'s queryIntentActivities, queryIntentservices, and queryBroadcastReceivers to see what applications are installed that will react to that intent.

Answer (score 16):

Let me recommend the app "ManifestViewer". It lists intents for each installed app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer

Have a nice day !!

Comment: I'll check it out. thanks - https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&feature=search_result

Comment: Finally got around to checking this out. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it only lists some common intents, but not those that are used on the apps.

Answer (score 11):

Using the following command with my Nexus 6 on Nougat 7.0 I got the list of all intents:

`adb shell pm dump * | grep ' filter' | cut -d ' ' -f 12 | sort | uniq`

- First the command opens a shell into your device and does a [`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm) dump of every package.
- Then pipe that output to [`grep`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep) which only selects lines with the word 'filter.'
- Then pipe that output to [`cut`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut) which gives the text found at the 12th position of any spaces on that line.
- Then pipe that output to [`sort`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort) which sorts that list from A to Z.
- Then pipe that output to [`uniq`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uniq) which clears up duplicated Intents.

YMMV - give these a try one at a time. Add the next pipe as you see the results you want. Not sure if prior versions of [`adb`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) will give you different numbers of spaces for `cut`, for example.

And, if you wanted the results for just one package like Chrome you could use:

`adb shell pm dump com.android.chrome | grep ' filter' | cut -d ' ' -f 12 | sort | uniq`

Comment: Nice answer, but the `filter` part wasn't obvious. You need to put the entire path there with something like `"com.android.chrome/."`.

Comment: there is no `dump` option in my android 4 setup. `dumpsys package r` worked for me instead.

Comment: Thanks @Kristopher! Nice one. Worked for me in Android 9 device without the cut pipe: adb shell pm dump * | grep ' filter' | sort | uniq

Answer (score 8):

`adb shell dumpsys package <packagename>`  provides the list of activities and the corresponding intents of an application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download the APK for the app you're interested in (there are loads of totally trustworthy sites for this). Then install `apktool` (e.g. `brew install apktool`) then

```
apktool d The.apk
```

Then check in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.